# eth0 bridge created for some reason

Tags: 16.04, udev, network-bridge

I am trying to setup a bridge with my ethernet card (enxb8...), here is interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports enxb827eb5c8fcc
auto enxb827eb5c8fcc
iface enxb827eb5c8fcc inet manual
```

But what I end up after a reboot is two bridges

br0 with no interfaces
eth0 with interface enxb8...

When I do `brctl delbr eth0` and assign enx... interface to br0, all works.

What I found in log is that kernel does some magic

```
kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827eb5c8fcc: renamed from eth0   -> this is how enxX appears, ok
kernel: eth0: renamed from br0 -> this is the culprit
```

I don't understand why it creates eth0 bridge(!). I have no rules in `/etc/udev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Turns out there is a file /etc/systemd/network/50-cloud-init-eth0.link

It contained

```
[Match]
MACAddress=b8:27:eb:5c:8f:cc

[Link]
Name=eth0
```

When I changed eth0 to br0, all works as expected.